# Is there a way to make lodash copy property getters and setters?

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

In the following situation I am finding that lodash doesn't seem to copy the getter of the source object:

```
const _ = require("lodash");

let sourceObject = { };
Object.defineProperty(sourceObject, "abc", {
    get: () => 123
});

let cloneObject = _.cloneDeep(sourceObject);

console.log(sourceObject.abc); // 123
console.log(cloneObject.abc);  // undefined
```

Is there a way to achieve the above with the [lodash](https://lodash.com) module?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only if the defined property is `enumerable`. This will cause it to be detected with `Object.keys()` which is ultimately how lodash gets the list of property names. This is configurable when you define the property with the `{enumerable: true}` option, but it defaults to `false`, which is why `_.cloneDeep` isn't picking up your property.

See [the MDN docs for Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) for more details.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the super fast response!! works perfectly :D

Comment: It seems as if lodash deepClone will indeed find the getter if it is enumerable but will not make a copy of the getter in the new object. Instead it will access the value using the getter and clone that value raw. Resulting object clone seems to be missing the getter definition ???

Comment: Yes, getting the values is straightforward. Making a "true clone" for some definition of that is [complicated to put it mildly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object)

Comment: so reading the question, looks like it was about making a copy of the getter itself which cloneDeep is not capable of doing. Yet, your answer was accepted as working perfectly even though the solution does not clone the getter ..so go figure... :) I am struggling to find a method to deepClone an object that in its structure may contain basic getter..